# Cannot connect to sqlite3 DB within Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am a newbie and have followed several django streams (including django docs) to create a project.  While I understand Python (enough to create a project within Jupyter Notebooks) and am learning the  backend framework of Django, I find myself in the "weeds".

I understand creating models.py (my data), views.py (what I want to render in the view) and of course the .html to structure the "response" the user will see or the DB will iterate through to create the response.

I created a database with DB Browser through Sqlite.  I cannot connect to the db to "populate/import the data in the DB.  I can "add" all rows manually but that includes over 800 rows.  Should I look at csvimports from Django library or import CSVImport from Python?

All I want is a user input to iterate through a database to find a match.  From that match the return will render a response('You entered "X" and the results are:X - which will include a static file).

My github is: https://github.com/NinaMaxberry/Cornerstone-Project

Let me know what else is required.  I really want to learn Django.

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem here? You cannot connect to the legacy db, or you are making a new db? Can you pass your database settings from settings.py? Did you ran makemigrations, or migrate?

If your database is fine, you can create a simple model, or go through the existing one, with a simple form field.

After you made a model form, and passed it to your html, you would just need to GET users input from the form, in the simple view like this :

```
def myFunc(request):
    query = request.GET.get('user_input') #getting the user's input field name
    if request.method == 'GET':
        results = YourModel.objects.filter(desired_search_field=query)

    return render(request,'yourapp/yourpage.html',{'results': results})
```

Is that helpful?